# Tables locked in Active Record transaction

Tags: activerecord, codeigniter-2

It seems that I have got my tables locked. I can't really restart the mysql server beacause i dont have the privileged to do that.

So is there a way to unlock my table which got locked during a transaction.

I was using Codeingiter transaction as

```
            $this->db->trans_start();
            //multiple queries
            $this->db->trans_complete();
            if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
                       //some message
```

I am really stuck in it, Please help me out here

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution, Luckily PHPMYADMIN came to my rescue. There is a way to kill all the processes mysql is holding. We can simply go to home of phpmyadmin and then select processes. Then we can kill the processes that will unlock tables if they are locked. Worked wonder for me